# WSO2 APIM 1.10 - config endpoint secure scheme while adding api via REST-API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using APIM 1.10 to add new APIs via the REST-API (see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIsApi#apisPost) and it works fine but:

I want to add the security-scheme: "Basic Auth" for the api endpoint.
But I have no idea how to do this, because the endpointConfig-config is not described.

I need something like this: endpointSecured:true, endpointAuthDigest:"Basic", endpointUTUsername:"usN", endpointUTPassword:"pass"

Any ideas?

C ya,
Marty

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help you to achieve the requirement.

- Edit the API and go to the implementation tab.
- Click on "Show More Options".
- Select "Secured" for Endpoint Security Scheme.
- Provide the credentials and save.

Comment: This is the way if you use the Publisher UI, but I wants to know the way via REST-API

Answer (score 0):

When you create API using rest API, you can add secure endpoint details by adding following part. 
**&endpointType=secured&epUsername="admin"& epPassword="admin"**

Here is a sample command

```
curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d "action=addAPI&name=SampleAPI&context=/country&version=1.0.0&visibility=public&thumbUrl=&description=Check Country by Code&tags=country&endpointType=secured&epUsername="admin"& epPassword="admin"&tiersCollection=Gold,Bronze&http_checked=http&https_checked=https&resourceCount=0&resourceMethod-0=GET&resourceMethodAuthType-0=Application&resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0=Unlimited&uriTemplate-0=/*&default_version_checked=default_version&bizOwner=xx&bizOwnerMail=xx@ee.com&techOwner=xx&techOwnerMail=ggg@ww.com" -d'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}';
```